# Add custom headers before upload with Primeng's FileUpload component

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

How can we add custom headers to the http request (like the Authentication) of the file upload?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We use the `onBeforeSend` event:

```
private onBeforeSend(event) {
    event.xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("AccessToken"));
}
```

Comment: make sure you look at the events, onBeforeSend is before any request is made, so you'd need to add headers there, onBeforeUpload is only before the file(s)/form data are sent, that caught me.

Comment: onBeforeSend is no longer valid after primeNg 8 (angular 8), use headers property as input

Answer (score 4):

After Angular 8 onBeforeSend is no longer used need to used headers input property

in View

```
<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" url="./upload.php" [headers]="httpHeaders"></p-fileUpload>
```

in component

```
    httpHeaders:HttpHeaders ;

    httpHeaders.set('channel', Channel.AT.toString())
    httpHeaders.set('loginId', Settings.user.userId.toString())
    httpHeaders.set('sesnId', Settings.auth.token)
    httpHeaders.set('commVer', Settings.app.version)
    httpHeaders.set('clientIp', Settings.user.clientIp)  
    httpHeaders.set('uniqueRequestId', Guid.MakeNew().ToString();
```

Comment: Shall I route an issue to you?

Comment: I add this.httpHeaders = {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }; on component constructor . Works for me.